# Strange behaviour on for loop

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Good morning.

I'm using a for loop inside a funtion in Dahs-plotly (I don't know if this matters or not). The point is since the second iteration I'm having an strange behaviour of my loop working with pandas dataframes. Below I show an example:

```
list_items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

for item in list_items:

    info = df_base[df_base.item == item].copy()
    More similar code...
```

In first iteration there is no problem, I obtain `item = 'item1'`, however, in second iteration, the code fails in `More similar code...` due to the iterator fails.

I'm using pdb package for debuging, and pause the code just above `info = df_base[df_base.item == item].copy()`. My surprise comes when, with paused compilation, sometimes `item = 'item1'` and sometimes `item = 'item2'`, while the right behaviour will be `item = 'item2'`.

This is the first time I get an error like this and I'm astonished, so looking for a solution online I've found iterators (in which, with each iteration, the values ​​of the iterator are eliminated), so my curret code is:

```
list_items = iter(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])
done_loop = False

while not done_loop:
    try:
        item = next(list_items)
    except StopIteration:
        done_loop = True
    else:
        info = df_base[df_base.item == item].copy()
        More similar code...
```

But the error is still the same.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks you very much in advance.

**EDIT**

I've deleted all the code below `info = df_base[df_base.item == item].copy()`, so my code now is:

```
list_items = iter(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])
done_loop = False

while not done_loop:
    try:
        item = next(list_items)
    except StopIteration:
        done_loop = True
    else:
        info = df_base[df_base.item == item].copy()
        print iter
        print info
```

And I'm getting still the same error on my prompt: `iter1`; `(right info 1)`; `iter2`; `iter1`; `(right info 2)`; `iter3`; `(wrong info 1)`; and so on...

**EDIT 2**

```
import pandas as pd

data      = {1.0: [0,1,2,3,4], 2.0: [54,12,32,45,78], 'table': ['t1','t1', 't2','t3','t4']}
info_base = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

list_tables = iter(info_base.table.unique().tolist())

done_looping = False

while not done_looping:
    try:
        table = next(list_tables)  
    except StopIteration:
        done_looping = True
    else:
        info  = info_base[info_base.table == table].copy()
        print table
        print info
```

Comment: `list_items` is clearly actually not a list, because you can't call `next()` on a list, so what is the type of this object?

Comment: Sorry, just omit some code. Check edit.

Comment: iterating over a list shouldn't raise `StopIteration`, the issue must lie in "More similar code...", maybe you modify the list size while iterating

Comment: Can you also add whatever possible in `more similar code` as well? give minimal runnable code that others can reproduce the issue with.

Comment: I understand you, but even if the error does not occur because I pause the compilation before, I have verified that the problem comes from this strange behavior of the iterator, that is, the code in `More similar code` is not the problem. In addition, responding to @Chris_Rands , the list list_tables does not change within the loop, neither in one case nor in the other.

Comment: Well, before calling python code into question you should really check again your code in `More similar code`...

Comment: Check my edit please.

Comment: We need to either see the all code or a [mcve]. If the code you have is too long, please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've just prepared a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but no errors occur... I really think that the problem may come from using Dash ... I'll give you the example anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment your question, but are you using your for loop to dynamically create callbacks?

If yes I have faced the same problem and solved it by getting some id of my component thanks to a State in the callback

for exemple:

```
for component_id, component_property in dash_layout_components.items():
    @app.callback(
        Output(component_id, component_property),
        [Input(key, value) for key, value in set_back_and_display_graph_input.items()],
        [State(component_id, 'id')]
```

I had to get the iterator value inside my function, but I faced the same problem than you, so I added the component_id as State to be able to have it inside the function